# How to align views at the bottom of the List view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="47dip" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_bar" android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt_SEARCH_TITLE"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Description" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textColor="#fff"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
   android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/job_match_bg" >

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/viewmore"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am new i android developement and i don't have idea to develop this plz help
and also i want to add at Bottom

textView width fiil_parent
and left Button and text at center and right Button

sorry for bad English Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you in advance

```
     moreButton
```

---

```
      textView
```

L-Button     text       R_button

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking for `L-Button Text R-Button` you need to add a `linearLayout` horizontally, then add a button- text- button and add weights to them to make it look nicer try this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="47dip" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@drawable/tab_bar" android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt_SEARCH_TITLE"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Description" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dip"
    android:textColor="#fff"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1" //*** this is important to make the list float over button-text-button
    android:layout_below="@+id/rel_jobDesc"
android:background="@drawable/job_match_bg" >

</ListView>

<LinearLayout // here what you care about
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TExt!!"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Right" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

you should have the following PIC: **P.S: I dont have the pics so i changed the background color**

[image]

Get the idea, and stir the code the way you like. if you didnt get the idea, feel free to ask me. Hope I got what you want.

**---------------------------------Edit------------------------------------------**

here is to add a new line above the linearLayout and under the ListView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/main_bg"
>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="47dip" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
android:background="@drawable/tab_bar" android:id="@+id/rel_jobDesc">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt_SEARCH_TITLE"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:text="Description" android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20dip"
android:textColor="#fff"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/AboveLinear"  //*** this is important to make the list float over button-text-button
android:layout_below="@+id/rel_jobDesc"
android:background="@drawable/job_match_bg" >

</ListView>

<TextView //this is the text the is between linear and list
android:id="@+id/AboveLinear"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="Right here what ever you want" />

<LinearLayout // here what you care about
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="Left" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TExt!!"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:text="Right" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

it will look like this:

[image]

Glad I could help,  **Please be aware of the ID i gave to the components**

Comment: thanks foe replay and it's very useful but we also want to add one more textiew at top of the left right button at center

Comment: its perfect i checked but i also want text view  http://i.stack.imgur.com/X1URK.png show this image **"Take advantage of our free primium membership"**plz sujjest me how we can add this in you xml code

Comment: I added it.. check the second picture where "Right here what ever you want" you can change it to "Take advantage of our free primium membership"

Answer (score 0):

use this property for for button

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/list"
```